# how i solve this error The type or namespace name 'ThemeInfo' could not be found

Tags: c#

how i solve this error

The type or namespace name 'ThemeInfo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

AssemblyInfo.cs

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Resources;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Emgu.CV.WPF")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]

// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible 
// to COM components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from 
// COM, set the ComVisible attribute to true on that type.
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]

//In order to begin building localizable applications, set 
//<UICulture>CultureYouAreCodingWith</UICulture> in your .csproj file
//inside a <PropertyGroup>.  For example, if you are using US english
//in your source files, set the <UICulture> to en-US.  Then uncomment
//the NeutralResourceLanguage attribute below.  Update the "en-US" in
//the line below to match the UICulture setting in the project file.

//[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)]


[assembly: ThemeInfo(
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, //where theme specific resource dictionaries are located
    //(used if a resource is not found in the page, 
    // or application resource dictionaries)
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly //where the generic resource dictionary is located
    //(used if a resource is not found in the page, 
    // app, or any theme specific resource dictionaries)
)]
```

Comment: There should be a line reference. Post your code?

Comment: You are probably missing a using statement or a reference :).  Without context, this is really hard to help with.  Make sure you have the appropriate namespaces in your using statements and that you have all required assemblies refernced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a reference to `PresentationFramework.dll`. You have the correct `using` statement (`using System.Windows;`).

Answer (score 0):

I had to add

```
windowsbase.dll
PresentationFramework.dll
Presentationcore.dll
```